# How do I remove this floating shelf?

Tags: removal, shelf

Recently moved into a new place with a little floating shelf attached to two walls (corner). I initially assumed it was a generic Ikea floating shelf and would have a bracket that would easily come off. However, that does not seems to be the case. I do see what looks like some sort of bracket through the hole drilled for wires, but I cannot figure out how to remove it from the bracket itself (if that is even what that is).

Any tips or hints before I take a sledge hammer to it or yank it off the wall using force? The walls are concrete if that makes a difference.

[image: looking down into the wire hole]

[image: under side of shelf]

[image: under side of shelf]

Larger pictures can be found here: https://imgur.io/a/NvflRjB

Cheers

Comment: You might try impacts from a heavy hammer from below to see if it pops off some bracket fastened to the concrete.

Comment: Or try to force a prybar between the long edge of the shelf and the wall.

Comment: You say you moved into this place...do you own or rent?

Comment: I would first start by using a razor knife to cut the caulk on both walls all the way around and as deep as you can. It may be held in place with only that.

Comment: You are sure they are concrete walls? Where is this at? Not many buildings are made with concrete walls as an interior surface unless it is a basement wall in an older home. It could be plaster if it is an older building in the States or UK.